# What is the difference between "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage" in magento's cache management?

Tags: magento

What is the difference between "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage" in magento's cache management?

[image]

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Sometimes the cache location (like `/tmp/`) or service (like Memcache) is shared with other applications. "Flush Magento Cache" removes only those entries that Magento reliably tracks as its own. "Flush Cache Storage" clears everything but might affect other applications if they're using it.

Normally the location is `var/cache/` in Magento's folder so is not shared after all. It is safe to use either button. Sometimes (rarely) entries are not clearly tagged or Magento loses track of them and only the second button has an effect on them. I tend to use the second button when I'm having difficulty tracking down the cause of a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I've always wondered what the heck "may contain another data" meant.

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of using the nuclear option and use "Flush Cache Storage". If that doesn't do it then navigating to var/cache and nuking all the mage--? directories does the trick.

Comment: @Nicholas if your memcache/apc instance is used by other applications as well they will get flushed too

Comment: @Fiasco - Since either flush button loads the page again another request is made to Magento which immediately starts making new `mage--*` directories. Manually deleting the same must be the ultimate since it doesn't cause new cache entries. [MageTool](https://github.com/alistairstead/MageTool) has a clear cache command for this purpose.

Comment: **How** can it affect other applications ?? Each site on server has its own folders in their own directory. This is not clear, sorry

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Normally that would be right but sometimes it is not. Please read the answer again.

Comment: What functions are called when both buttons are clicked ?

Comment: @VickyDev The buttons call `Mage::app()->cleanCache()` and `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush()` respectively.  You can see this quite clearly in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CacheController.php`

Answer (score 26):

**Flush Magento Cache**

Removes all items in the default Magento cache (var/cache) and the var/full_page cache that have a Magento tag

**Flush Cache Storage**

Removes all items in the cache. This is the equivalent of deleting the entire contents of the cache folder on the server.If your system uses an alternate cache location, any cached files used by other applications will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As a practical example, if you use magento's cache for your own devices, eg;

```
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
$cache->save("My cached text","cache_name",array("my_cache"),60*60*24);
echo $cache->load("cache_name");
```

You will need to use **flush cache storage** to clear this if you make an update.

In my case it's for a dynamically generated 3 level off canvas menu.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the difference between “Flush Magento Cache” and “Flush Cache Storage” below:

Flush Cache Storage: This function basically clears out the entire cache, all cache tags. This calls the “flush()” function on “core/cache” model.

Flush Magento Cache: This function clears cache tags “MAGE” and “CONFIG”. This class the “clean()” function in “core/cache” model.

Answer (score 1):

**Magento Cache:**
Remove all items in the default Magento cache (var/cache).According to its associated Magento tag.

**Flush Cache Storage:**
Remove all items from the cache regardless Magento tag. If you used another location used by other application will be removed in this process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your query:

**Flush Magento Cache**
When you perform this action, the contents having Magento tag in var/cache and var/full_page_cache are removed.

**Flush Cache Storage**
Well, it removed all contents of cache. In case you are using alternate cache location or application such as **Varnish Cache** which is a web application accelerator also known as a caching HTTP reverse proxy. Then it will remove cache from there too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush cache storage if you modify the columns of a table (add or remove column) because *magento* executes a mysql `DESCRIBE` query and then saves the result in cache. 
This cache is not cleared if you only click on "Flush Magento Cache" button.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, cache:clean deletes all enabled cache related to magento whereas cache:flush deletes the whole cache storage, whether its magento cache or any third party cache (whether enabled or disabled)

Answer (score 0):

**Flush Magento Cache**
It's used to remove cache generated by default magento `var/cache` and `var/full_page`.

**Flush Cache Storage**
It's used to remove all types of cache(Magento cache and cache created by other external providers.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Cache: Remove all items in the default Magento cache (var/cache).According to its associated Magento tag.

Flush Cache Storage: Remove all items from the cache regardless Magento tag. If you used another location used by other application will be removed in this process.