# Magento "Flush Cache Storage"

Tags: magento, caching, cron, storage, flush

I understand the difference between "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage" in Magento ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955365/what-is-the-difference-between-flush-magento-cache-and-flush-cache-storage-i)). I'm trying to work on a cron job that will flush the cache storage from time to time.

I'm assuming that this button doesn't just remove the contents of var/cache/, but I can't find a solid resource that says what it does. I am using APC as well as all the inbuilt Magento cache features.

Is it possible to run the equivalent of the "Fluch Cache Storage" button from a script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CacheController.php`, you can see that `flushAllAction()` (the action that is called when you click `Flush Cache Storage`) is called.

This function contains the following:

```
/**
 * Flush cache storage
 */
public function flushAllAction()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_flush_all');
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__("The cache storage has been flushed."));
    $this->_redirect('*/*');
}
```

To call this in your own file, you can do the following.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

Now, you can run your php file using a cronjob.

Answer (score 3):

[here](http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/05/21/clearing-the-cache-in-magento/) you can find good explanation regarding difference between "Flush Cache Storage" and "Flush Magento Cache".

I agree that you should create CRON TASK (if clean cache is really necessary) ([how to](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)) with method:

```
public function flushAllAction()
{
    // Additional code if necessary
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
    // Additional code if necessary
}
```

If you need further help don't hesitate to ask.